How can I remove imprinted marks from my wood table?
I had a white mark on my wood table caused by putting a hot paper plate on it. I tried everything to remove the mark, then I read an article about putting a towel or tea-towel over it and steaming it with an iron. I tried it and completely removed the white marks.
But I used a thick tea-towel that had grids on it and now I have the grid marks where I just got rid of the white marks. I have tried polishing it out but the grid is still there. I also tried washing up liquid but to no avail.
It's not really noticeable but I can see it and drives me mad.
How can I get rid of the grid marks?

you said completely removed the white marks ... how are you seeing grid marks?

Do your steaming with the iron and a thin towel with no grid marks or a paper towel. Do it just enough to remove the grid marks.
